# if $|f'(x)|\le 4/5$ then is there a unique x such that $f(x)=x$

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable and such that $|f'(x)|\le \frac{4}{5}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then does a unique $x\in \mathbb{R}$ exists such that $f(x)=x$?

My approach:- For $f(x)$ being equal to $x$, $f'(x)$ should be equal to $1$ which is against $|f'(x)|\le \frac{4}{5}$ so there does not exist $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=x$.

Comment: How did you get "$f′(x)$ should be equal to 1" ?

Comment: Since $|f'(x)|\leq 4/5 < 1$ then f is a contraction map on $\mathbb{R}$ which is completed space with euclidean distance. Then we can use contraction map theorem to prove this problem.

Comment: @Akatsuki since$ f'(x) $ is continuously differentiable so $\lim_{x \to y}f'(x)=f'(y)$ that's why i think that $f'(x)$ should be equal to $1$ for $f(x)=x$

Comment: @MayankDeora How? There is little connection between what you said. Think carefully.

Comment: @Akatsuki sorry i correct my words :- $f(x)$ is continuously differentiable.

Comment: @MayankDeora This not my point. I mean $lim_{x\to y}f'(x)=f'(y)$ and $f(x_0)=x_0$ does not imply $f'(x_0)=1$.

Comment: One way you can see the problem with your approach is this: consider $f(x)=x/2$. It is continuously differentiable. Also $f(0)=0$, yet $f'(0)=0.5$

Comment: An easier way to see that your answer is off: consider constant functions.

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x)=f(x)-x$. According to [Bolzano's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), it is enough to show that there exist $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $g(x_1)g(x_2)\leq0$.

It is obvious that $-\frac{9}{5} \leq g'(x) \leq -\frac{1}{5}$, because $g'(x)=f'(x)-1$.

Hence, if $x_2 \geq x_1$ then $g(x_2) \leq g(x_1) - \frac{1}{5}(x_2-x_1)$ and if $x_2 \leq x_1$ then $g(x_2) \geq g(x_1) + \frac{9}{5}(x_1-x_2)$.

Therefore, if $g(x_1) \geq 0$ then there is an $x_2 \geq x_1$ which $g(x_2) \leq 0$ and if $g(x_1) \leq 0$ then there is an $x_2 \leq x_1$ which $g(x_2) \geq 0$. In both cases $g(x_1)g(x_2)\leq0$.